# Simple SQL query for Min and Max

Tags: sql

So I am trying to find the age of the oldest and youngest male and female patients along with the average age of male and female patients in the clinic I work. I am new to SQL but essentially it all comes from one table I believe which is named "Patients". Inside the Patients table there is a column for Gender which has Either M for male or F for female. There is also an age column. I am guessing this is really simple and I am just making this to complicated but could someone try to help me out?

My Query is pretty limited. I know that if you do something along the lines of:

```
Select 
    Min(AGE) AS AGEMIN, 
    MAX(AGE) AS AGEMAX
From Patients
```

Comment: Please include your query.

Comment: Warning: Storing an `age` column is going to bite you later - you'd be better off storing a `birthday` column instead.  Reason being: when do you update their age?

Comment: Yea I know the age column would normally not work but in this case the age is applicable to when they came here for a particular instance so it is not constantly changing.

My Query is pretty limited. I know that if you do something along the lines of:

Select Min(AGE) AS AGEMIN, MAX(AGE) AS AGEMAX
From Patients

On top of that I cant seem to SELECT Gender column when I run the above statement.

Comment: Since you said you are new to sql, I've heard good things about the book, Teach Yourself SQL in 10 Minutes.

Answer (score 6):

Use the [GROUP BY](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) clause:

```
    select * from @MyTable
```

- M 10
- M 15
- M 20
- F 30
- F 35
- F 40

  ```
  select Gender, MIN(Age), MAX(Age), AVG(Age)
  from @MyTable
  group by Gender
  ```
- F 30  40  35
- M 10  20  15

Comment: DOH! Forgot about the Group BY

Thanks! Still trying to get the hang of this.

Comment: So to piggy back off that group by...how do I get the Average age for Males and Average age for Females in the same query?

Comment: @user2052853 exactly as you would expect. Same as Min/Max. These are examples of [SQL aggregate functions](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_functions.asp), which are controlled by group by.

Comment: @CongXu in future, [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6e473/1) is nice addition to answers :)

Answer (score 2):

Here you go

```
SELECT gender, AVG(age) as avgage, MAX(age) as maxage,  MIN(age) as minage
FROM patients 
group by gender;
```

Comment: I was wondering about the downvote until I read the original answer.